# Sort a list by the values of a nested list

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools
import sys
import os
import glob
import math
import hilbert    
folder = sys.argv[1]

imgfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.jpg"))
dominant_rgb_color = []
files_domColor = []


for imgfile in imgfiles:
    color_thief = ColorThief(imgfile)
    dominant_rgb_color.append(list(color_thief.get_color(quality=1)))

for a, b in itertools.izip(imgfiles, dominant_rgb_color):
    files_domColor.append([a,b])

files_domColor.sort(key=lambda(r,g,b):hilbert.Hilbert_to_int([int(r*255),int(g*255),int(b*255)]))

for f in files_domColor:
    print f
```

I know how to sort the list only if I have the nested lists with the 3 digits. The way is here here

```
sort(key=lambda(r,g,b):hilbert.Hilbert_to_int([int(r*255),int(g*255),int(b*255)]))
```

but it's useful to have files that are connected with these 3 digits, so I put them in the list with the izip function. But now is it possible to sort again the list along with the 1st element I added? The output of the files_domColor list is

```
[['temp2\\11.jpg', [16, 17, 14]], ['temp2\\7.jpg', [40, 33, 27]], ['temp2\\8.jpg', [31, 26, 22]], ['temp2\\9.jpg', [39, 32, 25]]]
```

So, I want to sort all the lists. So the question is how can I take also in the sorting the [0] element of each list as I only know how to sort the [1] element?

Comment: could you explain it with an example ?

Comment: yes of course....
using that code sort(key=lambda(r,g,b):hilbert.Hilbert_to_int([int(r*255),int(g*255),int(b*255)]))
I can sort a list like [[16, 17, 14], [40, 33, 27],[31, 26, 22]], but how can I continue using that if I have a list like the above [['temp2\\11.jpg', [16, 17, 14]], ['temp2\\7.jpg', [40, 33, 27]], ['temp2\\8.jpg', [31, 26, 22]]

Comment: I belive you are on the right course with the import of itemgetter, but I don't see it used in your code. Have you studied [How to Sorting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html)?

Comment: just to be more specific the sort function sorts the colors from warmer to colder and it needs only a list with 3 digits to work. Just for combining the jpg files I have I added to the nested list the path of each photo. I don't know if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, like this?

```
sort(key=lambda(x):hilbert.Hilbert_to_int([int(x[1][0]*255),int(x[1][1]*255),int(x[1][2]*255)]))
```